# Degree of freedom and Grubler formula

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, degrees-of-freedom

I am attempting to apply the Grubler formula (which can be found here: https://learnmech.com/how-to-calculate-degree-of-freedom-of/) to determine the number of degree of freedom, but it does not seem to yield the expected in some cases.

Is it correct that there are some cases where the Grubler formula should be avoided? If yes, how can I recognize these cases and what method could I use instead?

EDIT: I've edited it to only ask about the underlying concept as required. Now, one might say that it lacks an example where it doesn't work ... tell me if that is the case, I'm just trying to comply.